# AS3 video event: How to trigger something when the video first plays

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the flash's video player to play a clip, autoplay is set to false. I need to trigger mc1 playing when the play button is first clicked, and trigger mc2 when the video completes.

Now I know how to do the complete trigger with:

```
videoPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, vidCompleteHandler);
```

But I have no idea what video event I need for when the video first plays, because I don't want mc1 to be triggered everytime the play button is clicked (i.e. if people click pause then play again, i don't want mc1 to be triggered again).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: just add an event listener to the play button and listen for click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach NetStream object to your video object at first and then listen for specific start event. It goes something like this:

```
// create a new net connection, add event listener and connect
// to null because we don't have a media server
ncConnection = new NetConnection();
ncConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
ncConnection.connect(null);

// create a new netstream with the net connection, add event
// listener, set client to this for handling meta data and
// set the buffer time to the value from the constant
nsStream = new NetStream(ncConnection);
nsStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
nsStream.client = this;
nsStream.bufferTime = BUFFER_TIME;

// attach net stream to video object on the stage
vidDisplay.attachNetStream(nsStream);

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
switch (event.info.code) {
    case "NetStream.Play.Start":
        yourStartFunction();
    break;
}
```

}